# How to create jar file with dependencies?

Tags: java, jar

I have an interface Operator in directory d:\oprinterface\Operator and four classes Plus,Minus,Multiply and Divide in diresctory d:\operators*  .These classes impelemet the Operator interface  . My main program (FileProcess) in directory d:\source\main\FileProcess use this interface and classes   .Now I want to create 3 seprate jar file from these interface and classes  . First of all I make jar file from Operator interface  .I do it like so  :

```
javac oprinterface/Operator.java
jar -cf oprInterface/Operator.class
```

After this step I compile and make jar file from classes Plus,Minus,Divide,Multiply  .because these classes depends on oprInterface.jar I create a manifest.txt file and write on it  :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: oprInterface.jar
```

And then compile and make jar file like so  :

```
javac -cp oprInterface.jar operators/*.java
jar -cvfm operators.jar manifest.txt operators/*.class
```

After doing this again I create a manifest.txt file for my main program  :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: source.main.FileProcess
Class-Path: oprInterface.jar;operators.jar
```

(after last line in manifest.txt I press enter)

Then I compile and make jar file like so  :

```
javac -cp oprInterface.jar;operators.jar source/main/FileProcess.java
jar -cvfm FileProcess.jar manifest.txt source/main/*.class
```

When I run my jar file (java -jar FileProcess.jar) I got this exception  :

```
NoClassDefFoundException : oprInterface/Operator
```

Did I make a mistake in creating jar files?

Comment: I should create jar file from command line

Comment: That depends, do you want a single jar or multiple jars

Comment: @ MadProgrammer at the end I want 3 seperate jar files  : 1-oprInterface.jar  2- operators.jar  3-FileProcess.jar these jar files have dependencies